# How to write mockito test case for uploading a file as shown in the below given controller?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan
public class FileUploadController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    /**
     * Upload single file using Spring Controller
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @PathVariable("name") String name) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(file);
        System.out.println(name);
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                Path path = Paths.get(env.getProperty("upload.dir.location"));

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(path + "/" +name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                logger.info("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my **application.properties** file

```
server.port=8082

spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

upload.dir.location=/home/user/Desktop/UploadedFiles/
```

I need a JUnit or Mockito(preferably) test case to test this code. I have tried few formats, but didn't find the perfect one so far. Can anybody suggest me to write unit test cases for uploading a file?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit-1**

Here is my test class:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RestapiFileUploadControllerTest extends RestapiFileuploadApplicationTests{

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
Environment env;

@Test
public void testUploadedFile() throws Exception{
    File f = new File("/home/user/Documents/response.pdf");
    System.out.println(f.isFile()+"  "+f.getName()+"  "+f.exists());
    FileInputStream fi1 = new FileInputStream(f);
    FileInputStream fi2 = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/user/Desktop/UploadedFiles/response"));
    MockMultipartFile fstmp = new MockMultipartFile("upload", f.getName(), "multipart/form-data",fi1);
    MockMultipartFile secmp = new MockMultipartFile("upload", "response.pdf","application/pdf",fi2); 
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/response")                
            .file(fstmp)
            .file(secmp))               
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("pdf", "response.pdf", "multipart/form-data", "data".getBytes());

    Path path = Paths.get(env.getProperty("upload.dir.location"));

    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/response", path)
                    .file(firstFile)
                    .param("some-random", "4"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

}
```

It is still saying that,
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
for both the test cases.

Comment: "I need a".. the point is that you start writing one, and we help out when you get stuck somewhere. we're not going to write custom made unit tests for you

Comment: This link can help you. https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/

Comment: Yeah, I have already written one thing. But, hesitated to include that file. Give me a while, I will add it with some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

With JUnit you can verify the file exists after the method is run.

```
@Test
    public void fileUpload_Success() {

        String fullPath = "C:\\test\\myFile.txt";

        //Your call here to upload the file.
        org.w3c.dom.Document myFile = buildTestFile();
        ExportFileToDisk exportComponent = new ExportFileToDisk();
        exportComponent.exportXMLFile(myFile, fullPath);

        File f = new File(fullPath);
        boolean fileExists = (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory());

        assertTrue(fileExists);
    }
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I need to add buidTestFile() method and ExportFileToDisk class right? What I need to include in those?

Comment: I'm giving you the outline to have a valid unit test that checks if a file has been output or not.  In the 3 lines under my comment above you need to call your methods that output the file.